# Concatenation on rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to ask a question about concatenation on rails4. I want to concatenate the two(2) inputted data and save to the database. These are my codes:

```
 a = playernum
 b = playername
 ref = "{#{a} #{b}}"
 s.player_id = ref
 sum_pts = Player.where(playernum: playernum).sum(:pts)
 sum_game = Player.where(playernum: playernum).sum(:gp)
 s.apts = sum_pts / sum_game
 s.save
```

the playernum and playername are the inputted data. and I want to concatenate them and store to the player_id and save to database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? Your code looks like it assigns the string `ref` to the `player_id` attribute of `s` (whatever `s` is), calculates a different value to assign to `s.apts`, and then saves `s`. Is that not what you want? Are you getting an error of some kind? We need more information.

Comment: there's no error. but the two inputted data did not concatenate at all. I don't know if my syntax on concatenation is correct.

Comment: Try using `s.save!` instead. It will raise an exception if the save wasn't successful, giving you more information. Also, usually an attribute whose name ends in `_id` (like `player_id`) is a foreign key (in this case corresponding to `Player#id`) and will have an integer value. It's strange that you're assigning a string like `{playernum playername}` to it. Could you post your model code as well?

Comment: ahmm.. sorry but all I want to ask is how to concatenate the two string. by the way, I realized that the player_id is integer. sorry my mistake. :)

Comment: I'll just change the player_id into varchar. It should not be an integer.

Comment: I think my codes now are working :) thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to know is how to concatenate strings:

```
s.player_id = "#{playernum}#{playername}"
```

will do the trick.

In your example, the extra curly braces you have surrounding your variables will actually be part of the string (which I would assume you don't want). So with your code, the output would look like this:

```
"{12345ana}"
```

FWIW, there's also no need to store your variables into another variable before concatenating - i.e. assigning `a` to `playernum`.